# Three dimensional array in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I apologize in advance if the title of this question is not right but I do not know how to word it. What I am trying to do is:

I want to show a table on this format.

```
                  week_1      week_2         week_3
sub_account_1     25 calls    35 calls       15 calls
sub_account_2     35 calls    17 calls       13 calls      
sub_account_3     26 calls    5 calls       11 calls
```

I am trying something like:

```
SELECT count(calls), date, sub_account_name
WHERE master_account = 12
AND date IN ('2017-01-07','2017-01-14','2017-01-21')
GROUP BY sub_account_name, date
```

This query is not showing what I want, instead is showing:

```
sub_account_1    week_1   35 calls
sub_account_1    week_2   25 calls
sub_account_1    week_3   17 calls
sub_account_2    week_1   13 calls
sub_account_2    week_2   11 calls 
......
......
sub_account_3    week_3    15 calls
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me how to write the query to produce the desired table.

Edit to show sample data:

There are two tables (Account and Call)

```
Account
ID           int
AccountId    int
Name         varchar(50)
master       int
```

master accounts and subaccounts are both same datatype and stored on the same table. If an account has accountId = master it means that it is a master account. All its subaccount will hold the accountId value of their master as a master value.

```
Call
ID            int
callId        int
date          datetime
f_accountId   int
```

I need all the calls on the following dates ('2017-01-07','2017-01-14','2017-01-21') on the format showed above.

Comment: sounds like you need a pivot, but you need to show the current data sample (i.e. what the data looks like before your query) to be sure.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name,[14] as 'Week 1',[15] as 'Week 2',[16] as 'Week 3'
FROM (SELECT [Name],DATEPART (WK,c.date) as 'Week'   
    FROM Account a  --Highlight this subquery to determine the week numbers
        JOIN [CALL] c ON a.AccountId = c.f_accountId
    WHERE [master] = 2
     ) p
PIVOT
(
COUNT(WEEK)
FOR WEEK IN ([14],[15],[16]) --These numbers are the week numbers
) as pvt
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect. I knew nothing about PIVOT in SQL. I will have to read some materials about this.